# couchdb, disabling rereduce

Tags: couchdb, mapreduce

I'm attempting to get a key value pair out of couch db.  The key is the player id, and the value is how many games exist where it's their turn.  I have a map method that successfully gets a list of playerID,gameID where the playerID is who's turn it is for the gameID.  My reduce function is a simple length call.

```
function(keys, values){
  return values.length;
}
```

When I run this from Futon, it runs fine.  I get the sample output:
5,11
6,3

However, when I call it from Divan (C# lib for couchdb), I get the result
null, 14

My guess is it's merging these into one item through a rereduce.  Is there a way to disable rereduce?

Thanks.

-Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't disable rereduce. However, the difference here is that Futon is adding group=true when calling your view but Divan is not, which explains the different results.

You should replace your reduce function with "_count" which correctly handles both the reduce and re-reduce cases. Your function returns the length of the values array, which is only correct for the reduce case. A correct solution in javascript would look like this;

```
function(keys, values, rereduce) {
  if (rereduce) {
    return sum(values);
  } else {
    return values.length
  }
}
```

In the reduce call, then the values array contains whatever you emitted as the value, one entry for each emit. Since you're counting, you don't care what that value is, only how many of them there were. In the re-reduce call, the values array contains values previously emitted by a reduce call. Here the length of the values array is completely irrelevant, instead you want the sum of the lengths of previous reduce phases.